# Duda con sorted al ordenar lista de enteros en forma de cadenas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo esta lista `A`:

```
A = ['-1', '-2', '-2', '1', '1', '10', '100', '20', '4']
```

si pongo `sorted(A)` me sale esto

```
['1', '1', '-1', '20', '4', '-2', '-2', '10', '100']
```

probé con esta lista:

```
lista = ['3', '2', '5', '6', '7']
```

y si repito este proceso, es decir `sorted(lista)`, me la imprime ordenada pero, por alguna razón, con los números negativos tengo problemas. No entiendo porque Python ya no la ordena adecuadamente.

Lo que necesitaba era que me **organizara una lista de números string, sin necesidad de volverlos enteros y sin usar algún ciclo**.

¿Alguna idea de el por qué ocurre y de si se puede solucionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tu lista es una lista de cadenas, Python las ordena como tales usando para ello los `codepoints` unicode. Esto causa que, por ejemplo, '103' sea considerado menor que '3', ya que '1' es menor que '3'.

Si no deseas pasar tu lista a enteros, simplemente usa el argumento [`key`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) de `sort`:

```
>>> a = ['5', '101', '47', '-4', '-14', '0']
>>> a.sort(key=int)
>>> a
['-14', '-4', '0', '5', '47', '101']
```

O con `sorted`:

```
>>> a = ['-1', '-2', '-2', '1', '1', '10', '100', '20', '4']
>>> sorted(a, key=int)
['-2', '-2', '-1', '1', '1', '4', '10', '20', '100']
```

Ten en cuenta que `sorted` retorna una nueva lista, copia ordenada de la original, mientras que `list.sort` ordena la lista original directamente.